# Java - elastic search

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch

Here I'm trying to make a java application and use elasticsearch in the application as a first stage i have made a simple Dynamic Web Java application with spring. In this application(Simple employee records application) I have a privileged login (Admin & User).

- Admin - He has all permission
- User - Read and edit permission alone

I'm trying to make use of elastic search in this application

Hope you would Help me to make use of the elasticsearch in the application so that I would be able to understand better about the elastic search.

Comment: Please be little more specific about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch has provided sufficient number of the java api to get search result by applying query and filters.

Check this link for more details :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        Settings s = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", SEARCH_CLUSTER_NAME).build();
        SEARCH_CLIENT = new TransportClient(s)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                        SEARCH_HOST, Integer.parseInt(SEARCH_PORT)));

        SearchResponse searchResponse = SEARCH_CLIENT
                .prepareSearch(SEARCH_INDEX_NAME)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000))
                .setTypes(SEARCH_TYPE_NAME)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        while (true) {
            searchResponse = SEARCH_CLIENT
                    .prepareSearchScroll(searchResponse.getScrollId())
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).execute().actionGet();
            for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()) {

                jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(hit
                        .getSourceAsString());

            }
            // Break condition: No hits are returned
            if (searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Ansu  for Replaying ma query . It would be more helpful for me to understand if i get an example.

Comment: @VigneshPrasannaRadhakrishnan are you already aware of the elasticsearch queries and filters or you are using it for the first time.

Comment: No Ansu but long time back i have configured elasticsearch using logstash  to pull data from twitter using API . Here im trying to make a search operation or more than that in an application , im bit confused or im blank how to use it . this is for my POC only .

Comment: check out this code, this basically creates the elasticsearch client and fires the match all query to get all the result you can try different query depending upon your situations

Comment: Thankyou Ansu . your answer was really helpful for my POC .